# Adding/Updating object to/in nested array in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a document:

```
{
  "_id": "57d421bbbc44538f0634081c",
  "in_date": "1473724800",
  "bboxes": [
      { "bbox_index": "4124432432311", "data": {} },
      { "bbox_index": "4124435342332", "data": {} },
      ...
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to update entire object found in `bboxes` with specific `bboxes.bbox_index`:

```
bbox_index = 4124432432311
in_date = 1473724800

self.db['my_table'].update(
    {
        'in_date': in_date,
        'bboxes.bbox_index': bbox_index
    }, 
    {
        '$set': {'bboxes.$': dict(item)}
    },
    upsert=True
)
```

I expect this object `{ "bbox_index": "4124432432311", "data": {} }` to be replaced with `dict(item)`

This works fine when object with required `bbox_index` already exists. When it doesn't exist, I get `The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: bboxes.$`

In order to make it work I have to do the same query but instead of `$set` do `{'$push': {'bboxes': dict(item)}}`. Of course, this doesn't work well when I do already have required object in database. In this case I'm pushing same object again. Possible solution would be to check for the object before updating it but I wanted to make it in one single expression. I thought `upsert=True` was made exactly for this purpose. Is there any way to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$push`, you can use `$addToSet` which will insert a new entry in the array only if the entry doesn't exist yet.

To paraphrase the relevant manual page https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/:

> The **$addToSet** operator adds a value to an array unless the value is already present, in which case **$addToSet** does nothing to that array.

Comment: Hi @Kevin
Unfortunately, it doesn't work like this. I mean, yes, in general it does but if you try to use it for my particular case where I need both `upsert` and positional operator, you will get `The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: bboxes.$`.

Comment: I see what you mean. `upsert` was created for document-level operation, not sub-document level, so it will update or insert when the document doesn't exist. What you wanted requires a deeper object analysis, which is currently beyond the scope of the query language and best done in the application level.

Comment: I don't think so. It's just an update command that should insert an item in a nested array when it doesn't exist. Or update when it does. I don't see why should this be done at the application level.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/: `upsert boolean Optional. If set to true, creates a new document when no document matches the query criteria. The default value is false, which does not insert a new document when no match is found.` I don't think upsert will work for you though. For sub-document level, all you have is $set, $push, or $addToSet, so you either have to create a new document, or update an existing one.